# How to filter an item in one queryset from appearing in another queryset in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a Django view where I am getting the first queryset of 'top_posts' by just fetching all the Posts from database and cutting it in the first four. Within the same view, I want to get "politics_posts" by filtering Posts whose category is "politics". But I want a post appearing in 'top_posts', not to appear in 'politics_posts'.
I have tried using exclude but it seems like it`s not working. Below is my view which is currently not working:

```
def homepage(request):
    top_posts = Post.objects.all()[:4]
    politics_posts = Post.objects.filter(category='news').exclude(pk__in=top_posts)
    context={"top_posts":top_posts, "politics_posts":politics_posts}
    return render(request, 'posts/homepage.html', context)
```

Any help will be highly apprecuiated. Thanks.

Comment: Just filter by the right category `Post.objects.filter(category='politics').exclude(pk__in=top_posts)`

Comment: @Niko the category has no effect

Comment: It should. The only option left is that you are retrieving an empty QuerySet. What is the result of `print(Post.objects.filter(category='politics'))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change your code to something like this using `values_list` to get only the pks in a list. Otherwise you are trying to compare a list of Post objects the `exclude` code

```
top_posts = Post.objects.all()[:4]
top_post_pks = top_posts.values_list('pk', flat=True)
politics_posts = Post.objects.filter(category='news').exclude(pk__in=top_post_pks)
...
```

Also maybe you need to do `category=politics`. In the question you have put `category=news`

Comment: Using the code you just provided, the url for going to post details fails to work. I get the error `Reverse for 'blog_details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['details/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/\\Z']`

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: I dont understand why whenever I print the ID for the `politics_posts` they come by skipping two like this `ID: 13
ID: 15
ID: 17`. All the posts in the database are under the politics category.

Comment: Are there any posts with id 14, 16, etc? You can use any database viewer tool to see what is in the database.

Comment: Yeah. They are there

Comment: When I print out their IDs with the code you provided, you can see there are posts being duplicated as seen in this output `Top Posts Slashed: 12
Top Posts Slashed: 13
Top Posts Slashed: 14
Top Posts Slashed: 15
Politics Posts: 13
Politics Posts: 15
Politics Posts: 17` The posts with IDs 13, 15, and 17 have been duplicated.

Comment: Can you update your question with more code, the html template, etc?

Comment: The html template is just some shady for loop to print the titles

Comment: Hey @Arun. It has finally worked. Seems I just had to restart my server. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sounds good 